# Dynamic memory allocation 2d array in C

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, dynamic

```
int **twoDary = (int**) (malloc(rows * sizeof(int *)));
int **twoDaryStart = twoDary;
int *currentrow;

for ( i = 0; i < rows; i++ ){  // Originally: for (i = 0; i < columns; i++)
    *(twoDary + i) =  (malloc(columns * sizeof(int)));
}

for (j = 0; j < rows; j++) {
    currentrow = *(twoDary + j);
    for ( i = 0; i < columns; i++ ) {
        *(currentrow + i) = i;
        printf("%d\n", *(currentrow+i));
    }
}
```

I'm trying to create a dynamic 2-D array. I am then trying to assign i ,the current i (in the inner for loop) to each element in every row. So my output should be the numbers 0 - column printed row times.

I keep getting a seg fault if my rows and columns are not the same i.e. 5 rows 10 columns. Can anyone see from this code why that would be happening?

Comment: @Code-Guru: actually, `currentrow` is initialized at its the first use inside the second loop.  The variable `twoDaryStart` is initialized but unused.  You might prefer to delete your comment.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your first loop should be:

```
for (i = 0; i < rows; i++)
{
    ...
}
```

---

Apparently the code was consistent (but wrong) — the same problem was in the `free()` code.  Here's my [SSCCE](http://www.sscce.org/) for the problem.  It is given a clean bill of health by [`valgrind`](http://valgrind.org/).

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

extern int **alloc_array(int rows, int columns);

int **alloc_array(int rows, int columns)
{
    int i;
    int j;
    int **twoDary = (int**) (malloc(rows * sizeof(int *)));
    int **twoDaryStart = twoDary;
    int *currentrow;

    for ( i = 0; i < rows; i++ ){
        *(twoDary + i) =  (malloc(columns * sizeof(int)));
    }

    for (j = 0; j < rows; j++) {
        currentrow = *(twoDary + j);
        for ( i = 0; i < columns; i++ ) {
            *(currentrow + i) = i;
            printf("%d\n", *(currentrow+i));
        }
    }  
    return twoDary;
}

int main(void)
{
    int **d2 = alloc_array(5, 10);

    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
        free(d2[i]);
    free(d2);
    return(0);
}
```

Comment: I literally just fixed that before your comment, but I retested and I still get a seg fault.. :(

Comment: Ah nevermind, I need to fix the same problem in a free loop; thanks!